# Alien circuit component

Tags: simulation, datasheet

I am modeling chip ‍`MC14538` in `PSPICE` by building its internal circuit from the datasheet. I, however, can't figure out what logic gate they are using. It seems like an OR gate with some sort of `circle` on one of its input terminals. Also, what is the component designated by **A**
[image: Schematic from datasheet]

Comment: 74'14 + 74'00 = ?

Answer (score 4):

The circle simply inverts that input, you can use a regular or gate with a not gate in place of the circle.

The other component next to input A looks to be a Schmitt Trigger, basically a buffer with hysteresis see [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger)

Comment: Having used that chip a fair bit, that diagram provide by the datasheet is a little off. The inverting one with a circle has an actual inverting schmitt gate in front of it. It is mentioned in the text of that datasheet and the older TI ones included it in the diagram, no idea why it was left out of the newer ones.

Answer (score 1):

The small circles on the inputs and /Q2 output indicate an inversion - the /RESET input is active low (hold LOW to reset).

Input A has a Schmidt Trigger input.

Answer (score 0):

The MC14538 may not be recommended for new design by some suppliers. In any case, check for the alternatives to copy from the library or consider as active parts.

Schmitt trigger the hysteresis function in the symbol, and circle means inverted input or output or active low edge trigger if desired in this case, beside the active high edge input. Your choice.

CD4047BMS , HS-82C85RH, HS-82C54RH